# Wrong file association for one file in IntelliJ / Android Studio

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, android-studio

I accidentally created a file without a .xml extension. I clicked through another dialog immediately after associating that file as some other type...? After renaming the file to include .xml the file still has no syntax highlighting. I've tried closing Android Studio, deleting the file and recreating, etc. It still shows up as a regular file. If I create a file with a different .xml file, it associates fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, a quick action to reassociate a file's type will be available in the context menu of the Project tool window in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (EAPs should be available publicly around May 2021).

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Look in the `Preferences > Editor > File Types` under `Text files`, the name of your file is probably there, remove it.

[image: Preferences > Editor > File Types]

---

If you cannot find it there, the next option is to search IntelliJ's caches for the name of the file, e.g., `find . -name "*.xml" | xargs grep "Whoopsies"`. IntelliJ has to be remembering that value *somehow*...

---

The cache locations depends on your operating system and IntelliJ version ([source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)).

#### Windows

Windows Vista, 7, 8:

```
\Users\[USER ACCOUNT NAME]\.[PRODUCT][VERSION]
```

Windows XP:

```
[SYSTEM DRIVE]\Documents and Settings\[USER ACCOUNT NAME]\.[PRODUCT][VERSION]
```

#### *nix

```
~/.[PRODUCT][VERSION]
```

#### Mac OS X

Configuration:

```
~/Library/Preferences/[PRODUCT][VERSION]
```

Caches:

```
~/Library/Caches/[PRODUCT][VERSION]
```

Plugins:

```
~/Library/Application Support/[PRODUCT][VERSION]
```

Logs:

```
~/Library/Logs/[PRODUCT][VERSION]
```

Comment: That was my first hunch, too :P. The only thing I have in Registered Patterns is *.9.png

Comment: @loeschg It _might_ be in one of the other "Recognized File Types", but rather than manually searching in the GUI, do a `find` in IntelliJ's caches (see edit), see if it's there. It might not even be in the "File Types" thing at all!

Comment: I just tried removing (renamed) the ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview folder, and it didn't fix the issue. I noticed that when I try to create a `New Drawable Resource`, Android Studio freezes for a second, and then I get an error that tells me the file already exists.

Comment: you are a beautiful person. Intellij's behavior seems a bit odd (I can't think of a valid use-case for this off the top of my head), but I wouldn't mind as much if the solution to this was easier to Google.

Comment: If you want a better way to do that in the future like a "Reassociate" action, upvote this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186794

Comment: picking up on the comment above. it seems like if you don't want to risk everything there is a specific file that lists re-associations. i used vs code and open the folder where the cache is (see list above for locations on platform), then i searched for the filename that was unintentionally re-associated to a different format. you can then delete that filename. it's in an xml. C:\Users\USERNAME\.AndroidStudio3.3\config\options\filetypes.xml that is where associations are mapped, and you can carefully change it from there without affecting entire installation configuration/cache state.

Comment: This is one of the most annoying issues if you can't find where IntelliJ remembers this file  association!

Answer (score 23):

I got the same sort of problem. I found my file in the following File Type:

[image]

Comment: If you want a better way to do that in the future like a "Reassociate" action - upvote this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186794

Comment: if you are using PyCharm then is it Settings>File Types>File type auto-detected by file content

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where I accidentally had a file be auto-detected as text in IntelliJ Idea.

Unfortunately whenever I would go to the File Types dialog like other answers suggest I could never find it there.

So I went to my IntelliJ configuration folder (see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) for where to find it) which for me was in `~/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/options` and found the `fileTypes.xml` file.

In there I found the line which contained the association for my specific filename and deleted it and saved the file.

Then I closed IntelliJ and reopened it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I myself found myself a victim of this one. Searched in vain to find any trace of this in cache files.

Managed to fix it by going back to `Preferences/Editor/File Types` then (because it was a kotlin type) typing the filename, in full, into the section `File name patterns` for Kotlin. Selecting reassign when a dialog pops up finally fixed this one - for me at least

Answer (score 0):

What seemingly worked for me on macOS Mojave 10.14.1 is removing `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.2`, but **this will reset *every* setting to the default**.

Answer (score 0):

I found it under the 'Auto-detect file type by content' file:
[Preferences/Editor/FileTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goGGD.png)

Answer (score 0):

just try to add a file into text file types, apply, after remove it and apply one more time. helped for me